# How does query execution on SQL Server from .NET differ from Management Studio?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, full-text-search

I investigated a problem when running a certain set of searches (from a .NET 3.5 application) against a Full Text Search DB on a SQL Server 2008 R2. Using profiler I extracted the long running query (120 seconds until Command Timeout was reached) and ran it in my SQL Server Management Studio. Duration was "0 Seconds" and depending on which one I tried 0 to 6 rows were returned.

The query looks like follows:

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'SELECT TOP 1000 [DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE].[ID] AS [Id], [DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE].[Title], [DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE].[FirstName], [ABOUT 20 OTHERS]
FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE]  
WHERE ( ( 
    ( Contains(([DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE].[Title], [DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE].[FirstName], [ABOUT 10 OTHERS]), @FieldsList1)) 
AND ( Contains(([DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE].[Title], [DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE].[FirstName], [ABOUT 10 OTHERS]), @FieldsList2))
AND ( Contains(([DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE].[Title], [DBNAME].[dbo].[FTSTABLE].[FirstName], [ABOUT 10 OTHERS]), @FieldsList3))
      ))'
,N'@FieldsList1 nvarchar(10),@FieldsList2 nvarchar(10),@FieldsList3 nvarchar(16)'
,@FieldsList1=N'"SomeString1*"'
,@FieldsList2=N'"SomeString2*"'
,@FieldsList3=N'"SomeString3*"'
```

The query looks a little weird as it is generated from an OR Mapper, but right now I don't want to optimize the query, as in SSMS it runs in less than one second, which shows it is not really the query making trouble.

I wrote a small testprogram:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("EXACTSAMECONNECTIONSTRING_USING_SAME_USER_ETC")
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = "EXACTLY SAME STRING, LITERALLY, AS ABOVE IN SSMS- exec sp_executessql.....";
command.CommandTimeout = 120;
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.NextResult())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
}
```

I got from my local PC also a SQLException after 120 seconds when command timeout was exeeded.

The SQL Server was at no moment under load heavier than a few single percent. There were no blocks at that table at any time during my tests.

I solved it after some time: I reduced the TOP 1000 to TOP 200 and suddenly the query from .NET code executed also in less than a second.

The questions I have:

1. Why in general is there such a huge difference between SSMS and simplest SQLCommand .NET code?
2. Why did reducing to TOP 200 have any effect, especially considering there were max 6 rows in the result.

Comment: ok, why downvote? Anything in this question that needs improvement?

Comment: Have you ruled out caching? Before you run the query in SSMS, run `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;`

Comment: Simply, querying directly from the source SQL engine will most likely process quicker than same query in a client. Though SSMS is a client, my guess is since it ships with the backend db, its layers are less involved than other apps. Other clients (.NET, Java, Python)  must remotely connect to interface with the database engine and hence must pass data across the channel.

Answer (score 2):

This is tied to how query plans are built. When you run it in SSMS, you probably replace the variables manually, so it's not the same.

You can read a full explanation here : http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

edit : maybe start with the paragraph "The Default Settings" and look at the results with manual enabling or disabling of ARITHABORT. This is the most common cause.

Comment: I ran the exact same query, nothing was replaced manually. EXACTLY as given above.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your question, but obviously you're fond of downvoting too. Your problem has its explanation in this article.

Answer (score 2):

So the preliminary answer (not yet fully verified due to its complexity) can be derived from Keorl's answer, or mostly from the link provided therein.

To describe the different symptoms, I'll explain what happens:

The SQL Server cached the query against the fulltext indexed table, which includes the execution plan of the query. This means, if the first query to run (which puts the plan into the cache) is a very rare query with an absurd execution plan, this plan is cached and used for all subsequent queries, ruining performance for most runs.

One thing I could reproduce in the end: rerunning the FT indexer/gatherer solved the problem (this time). Also here the explanation is simple: an index update throws away precompiled/cached queries. Thus a better query than the previously cached one could run as the first and store a much better overall plan in the cache.

**Answer to Q1: Why in general is there such a huge difference between SSMS and simplest SQLCommand .NET code?**

So why didn't this happen with SSMS? Also this can be extracted from Keorl's answer: SSMS circumvents this in setting ARITHABORT option, which results in its own newly compiled query which is then cached. Thus the different observations for the same query just using SSMS and Code.

**Answer to Q2: Why did reducing to TOP 200 have any effect, especially considering there were max 6 rows in the result?**

For Dynamic SQL as used in example above, cache is stored depending on hashes of the complete query. As the query is different for TOP 200 and TOP 1000 two different compiles would cached. Parameters are not part of the hash though, so queries with just changing parameters would still result in same cache entry being used.

Concluding this: Thanks Keorl for providing the means to find an answer.